# PHP check if url parameter exists

Tags: php, url, url-parameters

I have a URL which i pass parameters into

> example/success.php?id=link1

I use php to grab it

```
$slide = ($_GET["id"]);
```

then an if statement to display content based on parameter

```
<?php  if($slide == 'link1') { ?>
   //content
 } ?>
```

Just need to know in PHP how to say, if the url param exists grab it and do the if function, if it doesn't exist do nothing.

Comment: it's called isset(). `if (isset($_GET['...'])) { $slide = $_GET['...']; if ($slide == 'link1): ?> content <?php endif; ?>`

Answer (score 133, accepted):

Use [isset()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php).

```
if (isset($_GET["id"])) {
    // do something when a parameter exists
}
```

You can check the existence and equality in a single condition too

```
if (isset($_GET["id"]) && $_GET["id"] === 'link1') {
    // exists and equal to link1
}
```

However, it would be more convenient to define a variable first, using `??` shorthand, and then use it in a condition

```
$slide = $_GET["id"] ?? '';
...
if($slide === 'link1') {
    // equal to link1
}
```

Here, an empty string is used as a default value in case parameter is not defined. You can change it to any other value.

Comment: Older versions of PHP would let a simple `if($_GET['id']!='')` suffice. Stricter versions require this more explicit check I learned the hard way. While slightly annoying, I can appreciate that explicit and intentional coding builds great habits everywhere else and is a better practice, fundamentally. (can you tell I learned PHP on the web since the early 2000s?)

Answer (score 71):

```
if(isset($_GET['id']))
{
    // Do something
}
```

You want something like that

Answer (score 10):

Here is the PHP code to check if 'id' parameter exists in the URL or not:

```
if(isset($_GET['id']))
{
   $slide = $_GET['id'] // Getting parameter value inside PHP variable
}
```

I hope it will help you.

Comment: This was pretty well covered years before this answer was posted.

Answer (score 4):

It is not quite clear what function you are talking about and if you need 2 separate branches or one. Assuming one:

Change your first line to

```
$slide = '';
if (isset($_GET["id"]))
{
    $slide = $_GET["id"];
}
```

Comment: Why did you put `$slide = '';` at the beginning of the code? is it not superfluous

Comment: Nope it is not superfluous

Comment: So whats the purpose of it?

Comment: You should always define every variable which you are going to use.

Comment: Doesn't the 4th line define it? `$slide = $_GET["id"];`

Comment: Doesn't the 2th line make it conditional?

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an old question, but since php7.0 you can use the [null coalescing operator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php) ([another resource](https://stitcher.io/blog/shorthand-comparisons-in-php)).

> It similar to the ternary operator, but will behave like isset on the lefthand operand instead of just using its boolean value.

```
$slide = $_GET["id"] ?? 'fallback';
```

So if `$_GET["id"]` is set, it returns the value. If not, it returns the fallback. I found this very helpful for $_POST, $_GET, or any passed parameters, etc

```
$slide = $_GET["id"] ?? '';

if (trim($slide) == 'link1') ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just simplify it to if($_GET['id']). It will return true or false depending on status of the parameter's existence.

Comment: This will return false for urls like http://example.com?id=  and http://example.com?id=0