# How can I send parameters from controller to external URL

Tags: php, laravel, url, controller

I'm working with Laravel 5.8 and I'm trying to sent parameters from my controller to a php file that is not a view.
I've tried this way: 
`return redirect('my-route/?my-parameter='.'value');`
But I want to send it with POST method, how can I do that ?

Comment: What is the other `.php` file, controller, model, or something else? Not sure what you're asking here..

Comment: It seems OP wants to call a URL (outside their Laravel app) with the same arguments the controller received.

Comment: From what I understand, you are trying to make a request to an external url. Personally, I will use guzzle to achieve that, you can check more here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22355828/doing-http-requests-from-laravel-to-an-external-api, it might be helpful if you already know a bit about curl.

Comment: I want to send parameters to a file that exist in my public folder, i want him to receive those parameters just like the views do.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sending a request to another php application (or any application really) then I would also second @Nikolay and check out [Guzzle](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/). Or, another option would be to check out [Requests](https://requests.ryanmccue.info/) I've used both and both I think would get you what you're looking for.

Either option works great when communicating server-to-server (not an ajax call to an internal controller method).

The `php` file in your `public` folder will need to be able to check for such request(s). Without knowing what that file looks like, somewhere/how you'll need to [check if there are query parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18271173/php-check-if-url-parameter-exists).

Hope this helps!